# communication between c++ and java

Tags: java, c++, sockets, communication

I have to write a JAVA program which communicates with some other program in C++. Messages to send are simple String/Char[] like "REQ", "PAUSE", "02,14" with '\0' on the end, so: "REQ\0". I have this:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(komputer, port), czekaj);
in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

Sending:

```
public void sendTekst(String tekst){
    try{
        char []a = tekst.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            out.writeChar(a[i]);
        out.writeChar((byte)'\0');
        out.flush();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ramka, "Blad wysylu: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Reading:

```
String s = null;
char aa;
while((aa = in.readChar()) != '\0'){
    if(s == null)
        s = String.valueOf(aa);
    else
        s += String.valueOf(aa);                
}
```

**Problem:** I send "REQ" to C++ program (work on localhost on valid port). It received only garbage. I tried to do it on the same program (Java communicate Java) and it worked. **What do I need to do?**

I cannot edit the C++ program.

**EDIT:** I've changed input and output streams, but there is still problem:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Sending:

```
public void sendTekst(String tekst){
     tekst += '\0';
     char []a = tekst.toCharArray();
     out.print(a);
     out.flush();
}
```

Reading:

```
String s = null;
char[] aa = new char[20];
in.read(aa, 0, 10);
s = charToString(aa);
```

My method charToString:

```
public static String charToString(char[] buff){
    String str = String.valueOf(buff[0]);
    for(int i = 0; buff[i] != '\0' || i < buff.length ; i++)
        str += String.valueOf(buff[i]);
    return str;
}
```

I've tested this **only** for JAVA. I received garbage.

Comment: It would be nice to know what the garbage actually is, preferably in hex.  One thing to notice is that in java char is a single 16-bit Unicode character, while in C++, char is 8-bit.

Comment: It might not be the reason for your problem, but when sending text over network, especially if you use different operation systems or programming languages, you should always manually choose the encoding on both sides, to make sure they are written and read in the same way.

Comment: I changed to send it to UTF-8, but still is a problem