# JAVA: I can't read text from sockets, send by C++ program

Tags: java, c++, sockets

> **Situation:** I have program in JAVA and program (**only exe; I can't have access inside**) in C++. They are sending and receiving text for e.g. `"REQ", "00", "1,3", "15,4", "PAUSE"`. Communication goes like this (sending):

```
J: REQ
C: 00
J: NEW
C: 10
J: RDY
C: 2,13
J: 20
C: RDY
J: 1,1
(...)
```

First `RDY` made a repeated commands: `RDY` `number,number` `20` `RDY` (...).

Numbers: 0 - 15.

**Receiving:**

```
 char[] bb = new char[10];
 int znaki = in.read(bb);
 bb[7] = '\n';
 String s = new String(bb, 0, 7);
```

**Problem:** I read numbers like:

```
Send: 2,13
Received: 2,
Send: 3,15
Received 3,1
Send: 13,2
Received: 13,
```

But sometimes I have IOExeption: "Input length = 1"

**Is there any solution, to read properly?**

Comment: So http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005553/communication-between-c-and-java is solved and now you can read in C++ what is sent in  Java?

Comment: `byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; int znaki = in.read(buf); String s = new String(buf, 0, znaki, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);`

Comment: When I read f.e.g "REQ" to `char a[10]`, 7 chars are empty (not garbage). I didn't checked it carefully :P

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that in C/C++, a `char` is one byte, wheras a Java `char` is 2 bytes. Try reading into a `byte` array first (of the proper length) and then create a char array of the same length and copy every byte by casting it to a `char`. I'm sure you can do also some magic with stream encodings, but for your simple example, this should do!

Comment: "*then create a char array of the same length and copy every byte by casting it to a `char`*" - that is not the correct way to handle byte-to-char conversions. It will only "work" if the bytes are 7-bit ASCII. For anything else, you should be passing the byte array to the `String` constructor with the proper charset specified, or use `Charset.decode()` or `CharsetDecoder`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @loonytune, but I resolved it in different way. In Java and C++ program we add '.' at the end of the string, f. e. g.: "REQ." and everything is fine :)